# Get query data to view

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core

I'm new in ASP.NET Core 3.1 and I'm trying to pass query data (entity framework) to view.

This is my query

```
public void OnGet()
{
    var  query = (from panier in _context.panier
                         join product in _context.product on panier.id_product equals product.Id_Product
                         where panier.username == HttpContext.Session.GetString("username")
                         select new
                         {
                             product.nom_product,
                             product.Image,
                             panier.Qte,
                             panier.prix,
                             panier.Prix_total
                         });

            query.ToList();                
}
```

But I don't know how to call the result in VIEW

Comment: Are you using mvc razor or razor pages?

Comment: i'm using razor pages

Comment: noo , it's razor pages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should define a list in your PageModel. Below is a simple example:

**IndexModel:**

```
public List<User> Users { get; set; }

public void OnGet()
{
    Users = new List<User>
    {
        new User{ Id = 1, Name = "A"},
        new User{ Id = 2, Name = "B"},
        new User{ Id = 3, Name = "C"},
    };
}
```

And in the view:

```
@page
@model IndexModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home page";
}

@foreach (var u in Model.Users)
{
    <label>@u.Name</label><br />
}
```